# formatting a floating point number to be rounded to the .00 mark

Tags: python

Basically having issues with my print statement not being rounded

```
def getCounty(sales):
  return sales * .025

def getState(sales):
  return sales * .05

def getCombo(sales):
  return countyTax + stateTax

sales = float(input("Enter the total sales for the month: $"))
countyTax = getCounty(sales)
stateTax = getState(sales)
combo = getCombo(sales)
print("The amount of county sales tax $", countyTax)
print("The amount of state sales tax $", stateTax)
print("The total sales tax (county plus state) $", combo)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "rounded to the .00 mark", you mean that you want your output rounded to 2 decimal places.  Why do you expect that your output would be rounded to 2 decimal places?  You haven't told Python that that's what you want.  Here's how to do that:

```
print(f"The amount of county sales tax ${countyTax:.2f}")
print(f"The amount of state sales tax ${stateTax:.2f}")
print(f"The total sales tax (county plus state) ${combo:.2f}")
```

Result:

```
Enter the total sales for the month: $555
The amount of county sales tax $13.88
The amount of state sales tax $27.75
The total sales tax (county plus state) $41.62
```